# How to determine in desktop application code if a web service called

Tags: c#, web-services, request, desktop-application, communication

I have a **Web Service** and a method written in C#.

```
[WebMethod]
    public double Avarage(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        double retVal

        // Send a, b, c parameters to desktop application and wait for response

        // Get the result into retVal from form application and respond the request

        return retVal;
    }
```

I want to pass Avarage method parameters to my windows form application and get a result from that in order to reply the request.

How can i do that? Any helps would be perfect.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what the question or the underlying problem is. You would also need to provide some code of your attempt in order to get help here.

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you mean, try posting man example of what you have tried and explain clearly why it did not work.

Comment: @ceskin   I think you are little bit confuse because what you are asking and what you want is different .... Are you want to get average through Web Service using Desktop Application ?